# Android Studio. Building signed APK. Get Key Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, keystore

I've been building release versions of my app for months, and now all of a sudden I get this error.
`Failed to read key ********  from store ***** Get Key Failed. Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.`
This is beyond frustrating.

What I've done so far

1. Read every post on this error and tried every solution
2. Verified my passwords are correct
3. Checked and unchecked "save passwords"
4. Verified my keystore location is correct

Comment: Try using the same password for the key and keystore file.

Comment: OMG! that worked.  You are awesome.  Post it and I'll accept it. I'm also going to see if it's possible to donate some of my reputation to you.

Comment: Not related but @SamChen answer also worked when trying to use codemagic (a ci-cd service ) to build my Flutter app.

Comment: No doubt, the fact that this works suggests a bug in Android Studio. Don't worry: Google may fix the bug one day.

Comment: Maybe an explanation for the "same" password for the keystore and the alias: If your keystore format is JKS, you can have different passwords, but if the format is PKCS12, there is a single password to be used for the keystore and the alias. You can view the format from the command line: `keytool -list -keystore store.jks`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you get error like `block not properly padded`, `bad key` or `PKCS12` when signing the App Bundle or APK, try using the same password for the key and the keystore file, it works for me.

Comment: And could you explain why they have to be the same?

Comment: @Tura I actually don't know, you can create a post for that.

Comment: It's worked. But doesn't know why.

Comment: Same here. To be clear, I had to use the keystore password in the "Key password" field, instead of the key's password

Comment: Worked for me. But I am somehow very irritated with this requirement.

Comment: Blocked for a while building releases, this unblocked me, just wondering why this works? 

Comment: Oh my god I just wasted like 3 hours because of several errors that all in the end led up to this ‍♂️

Answer (score 5):

Recently, Android Studio started to show a message: "***Warning: Different store and key passwords not supported for PKCS12 KeyStores. Ignoring user-specified -keypass value. in Android Studio***" - so, first of all, store and key passwords should be the same, like other people said.

Besides, after getting this error even using the same password, I realized that **we can't use characters like @ or $ on the passwords**.

Comment: I ran into this error having two different passwords. Setting up the same password and removing @ and $, solved the error

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of `!` symbol. It's so weird that I was able to create bundle with this password but can't create a next one.

Unfortunately I have to reset my key.
Here is where it in the console:

`Setup -> App signing -> Request upload key reset`

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Just Remove space from folder name ,where your jks file stored